# How to prevent vuetify navigation drawer wrap content?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am making a vuetify `v-navigation-drawer` with two lists.

If my window has enough height, the two lists looks good like this:

[image: drawer]

But if I resize my window height to be shorter, the second list wrapped to the bottom like this image:

[image: drawer wrapped]

My drawer template is:

```html
  <v-navigation-drawer
    id="nav1"
    permanent
    clipped
    app
    :width="drawerWidth"
  >
    <v-row class="fill-height" no-gutters>
      <v-col>
        <v-navigation-drawer id="nav2" permanent :mini-variant="isMiniVariant">
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item-group v-model="selectedId" mandatory>
              <v-list-item
                v-for="(item, i) in mainItems"
                :key="i"
              >
                <v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                </v-list-item-icon>
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-title v-text="item.name" />
                </v-list-item-content>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list-item-group>
          </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
          <v-list
            width="56px"
            style="background-color: darkred"
          >
            <v-list-item-group>
              <v-list-item
                v-for="(s, index) in subFunctions"
                :key="s.name"
                :value="index"
                style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px"
              >
                <v-icon style="margin: 16px">{{ s.icon }}</v-icon>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list-item-group>
          </v-list>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
```

I want the right list not to be wrapped, even if the scrollbar is visible.
How could I achieve this?

Comment: You should try to provide a minimal reproducible example. I think there is to little info to know for for sure what cause the second list wrap. One fix could be to add `position: relative` to the container (v-row) and `position: absolute` to the second list. But that is kind of hacky and I would suggest it only as last resort (at the very best). But there should be a better fix in your case. Is just that without an example to experiment on we can only try to guess... And even that is hard.

Comment: Don't post direct screenshots in question.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the scrollbar is generated by the `v-row`.

The default style of `v-row` has an attribute of `flex-wrap: auto`, so I have to modify my `v-row` to have `style="flex-wrap: nowrap"`.

Now since there is no scrollbar, the right `v-col` will not be wrapped anymore.